# Unable to add ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a `validates_zxcvbn` helper method like `validates_uniqueness_of` in Rails 4.

I put it along with my `zxcvbn_validator.rb` under app/validators like this:

```
require 'zxcvbn'

class ZxcvbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator 
  ...
end

# This allows us to assign the validator in the model 
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods   
  def validates_zxcvbn(*attr_names)
    validates_with ZxcvbnValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)       
  end 
end
```

But I still cannot use `validates_zxcvbn` in my model.rb

The error is

> lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing`:
>   undefined method `validates_zxcvbn` for Staff (call 'Staff.connection'
>   to establish a connection):Class (NoMethodError)

### UPDATE:

I attempted to separate `ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods` into `activemodel_validations_helper.rb` and put it under `app/helpers`.
Then, in my `Staff.rb` model file, I did the following:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActivemodelValidationsHelper
  ...
end
```

Then, I started the server and got this error:

> active_support/dependencies.rb:495:in 'load_missing_constant': `Unable
>   to autoload constant ActivemodelValidationsHelper`, expected
>   app/helpers/activemodel_validations_helper.rb to define it (LoadError)

**How do I include new validation helper method in Rails 4?**

Thank you!

Comment: If you put the `module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods … end` code in a folder whose content is auto-loaded (like config/initializers for example), it should work.

Comment: I am hoping if I can put it inside `app/helpers` or something, but I can't seem to make it work. Putting it under `config.initializers` will make it load before my validators are loaded. It still doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Client Side Validations's custom validator [tutorial][1], it uses

```
# This allows us to assign the validator in the model
module ActiveModel::Validations::HelperMethods
  def validates_zxcvbn_of(*attr_names)
    validates_with ZxcvbnValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
  end
end
```

and puts it under `config/initializer` to enable `validates_zxcvbn_of` in the model.

In addition, I already put `zxcvbn_validator.rb` under `app/validators`.

Special thanks to @taglia who mentioned the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create `app/validators` directory (you've done that already)
2. Create a file in there called `zxcvbn_validator.rb` with the following contents:

   ```
   class ZxcvbnValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

     def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
       result = Zxcvbn.test(value)
       unless result.score > 0
         record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "not very secure...")
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Now in your model, you can just say

   ```
   class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :password, zxcvbn: true
   end
   ```

Here is a working example - https://github.com/kalmanh/zxcvbn-custom-validator

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am able to do `validates :password, zxcvbn: true`. But I am looking for transforming this into `validates_zxcvbn_of :password` with the help of custom helper method like these ones `http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validation-helpers`. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: I believe this syntax is preferred since you can apply multiple validators on the same line. `validate :password, presence: true, zxcvbn: true` and so on

Comment: Do you mind providing the source of your statement as in "this syntax is preferred"? Because I am looking to use `validates_zxcvbn_of` to match up with other of my validations such as `validates_presence_of` and `validates_uniqueness_of` to enhance readability

Comment: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/topics/models/validations.html It's the newer syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the article,but it says `In my opinion, the newer syntax is not good. Clean Ruby reads like English. ` and `Aaron Patterson on the Rails core team confirms that there are no plans to deprecate the older syntax.` I suppose two can coexist.

Comment: Yep. I saw that. He also lists the "reason" for the 2nd one "The Rails 3 style shines when we add in a second validation on the same field"